# Android how to wait for a callable in Splash Screen in android

Tags: android, splash-screen, executorservice

My scenario is i have 5 threads parallel  call to happen in splash activity but i need to wait for one specific thread( which is DashBoardCallable)  exectuion so that i can load dashboard data, show the splash screen untill dashboard data gets loaded  and once dashboard data get loaded change the activity meanwhile in parallel i load some more data related to that user in background(which is thread util class will do ).

or you can understand this way i have a ExecutorService of 5 threads for parallel calls and Splashscreen is based on one thread execution out of 5. Once this thread execution is done change the activity leaving rest other thread execution in background.

below is splash activity code :

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

            SharedPreferences        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.mypreference_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            ThreadUtil datatype1 = new ThreadUtil(editor,3504,"URL","DATATYPE1","DATATYPE1");
            ThreadUtil datatype2 = new ThreadUtil(editor,3504,"URL","DATATYPE2","DATATYPE2");
            ThreadUtil datatype3 = new ThreadUtil(editor,3504,"URL","DATATYPE3","DATATYPE3");
            ThreadUtil datatype4 = new ThreadUtil(editor,3504,"Different URL","DATATYPE1","DATATYPE1");
                    DashBoardCallable dashBoardCallable = new DashBoardCallable(SplashScreenActivity.this,3504);
    FutureTask<String> dashboardFuture = new FutureTask<String>(dashBoardCallable);
            executor.execute(datatype1);
            executor.execute(datatype2);
            executor.execute(datatype3);
            executor.execute(datatype4);
executor.execute(dashboardFuture);
            String response =dashboardFuture.get();
```

This is dashboaord callable :

```
public class DashBoardCallable implements Callable<String> {
    private Context context;
    private int user_id;
    public DashBoardCallable(Context context,int user_id){
        this.context = context;
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();

        httpUtil.setUrl("URL");
        httpUtil.setType("GET");

        return httpUtil.getStringResponse();
    }
}
```

this is threadUtil class:

```
public class ThreadUtil implements Runnable {
    private int user_id;
    private String url,type,stored_name;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public ThreadUtil( SharedPreferences.Editor editor, int user_id, String url, String type,String stored_name){
        this.editor = editor;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.url = url;
        this.type = type;
        this.stored_name = stored_name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();
        httpUtil.setUrl(url);
        httpUtil.setType("GET");
        String jsonresponse =httpUtil.getStringResponse();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        switch (type){
            case "DATATYPE1":
                saveDATATYPE1(jsonresponse,gson,editor);
                break;
            case "DATATYPE2":
                saveDATATYPE2(jsonresponse,gson,editor);
                break;
            case "DATATYPE3":
                saveDATATYPE3(jsonresponse,gson,editor);
                break;
        }


    }

    private void saveDATATYPE1(String jsonresponse, Gson gson,SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        if(!jsonresponse.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
            editor.putString(stored_name, jsonresponse);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    private void saveDATATYPE2(String jsonresponse, Gson gson, SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        try {
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<AssessmentPOJO>>() {}.getType();
            ArrayList<AssessmentPOJO> dashboardCards = (ArrayList<AssessmentPOJO>) gson.fromJson(jsonresponse, listType);
            for(AssessmentPOJO assessmentPOJO:dashboardCards){
                System.out.println("XXBBXBXBXBXB -> "+assessmentPOJO.getName());
                if(assessmentPOJO != null){
                    editor.putString(stored_name+assessmentPOJO.getId(), gson.toJson(assessmentPOJO));
                    editor.apply();
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        }catch (JsonSyntaxException jse){
            jse.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
    private void saveDATATYPE3(String jsonresponse, Gson gson,SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        if(!jsonresponse.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<CoursePOJO>>() {}.getType();
            ArrayList<CoursePOJO> coursePOJOs = (ArrayList<CoursePOJO>)gson.fromJson(jsonresponse, listType);
            for(CoursePOJO coursePOJO:coursePOJOs){
                if(coursePOJO != null){
                    editor.putString(stored_name+coursePOJO.getId(), gson.toJson(coursePOJO));
                    editor.apply();
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        }
        }
}
```

this is HttpUtil class:

```
public class HttpUtil {
    private String url;
    private String type;
    private HashMap<String,String> param;
    private String postrequest;
    public HttpUtil(){}
    private int socketTimeOut=0, connectionTimeOut=0;

    public HttpUtil(String url, String type, HashMap<String, String> param,String postrequest) {
        this.url = url;
        this.type = type;
        this.param = param;
        this.postrequest = postrequest;
    }


    public String getStringResponse(){
        String jsonresponse="";
        try {
            System.out.println("url "+url);
            System.out.println("type "+type);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = getHttpResponse();
            if (httpResponse != null && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                jsonresponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                if(jsonresponse.equalsIgnoreCase("[]")){
                    jsonresponse="";
                }
                System.out.println("HttpUtil Response is .... " + jsonresponse);
            } else {
                return "null";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonresponse;
    }
    public void getVoidResponse(){

    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(HashMap<String, String> param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    private HttpResponse getHttpResponse(){
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try{
        switch(type){
            case "GET":
                if(socketTimeOut != 0 && connectionTimeOut != 0){
                    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, connectionTimeOut);
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, socketTimeOut);
                    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                }
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

                break;
            case "POST":
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                if(param != null) {
                    for (String key : param.keySet()) {
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, param.get(key)));
                    }
                }
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                break;
            case "PUT":
                HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
                if(postrequest != null){
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(postrequest);
                    se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");//text/plain;charset=UTF-8
                    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
                    httpPut.setEntity(se);
                    httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                }
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
                break;
            default:
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                break;
        } }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }catch (JsonSyntaxException jse) {
            jse.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return httpResponse;
    }

    public String getPostrequest() {
        return postrequest;
    }

    public void setPostrequest(String postrequest) {
        this.postrequest = postrequest;
    }

    public int getSocketTimeOut() {
        return socketTimeOut;
    }

    public void setSocketTimeOut(int socketTimeOut) {
        this.socketTimeOut = socketTimeOut;
    }

    public int getConnectionTimeOut() {
        return connectionTimeOut;
    }

    public void setConnectionTimeOut(int connectionTimeOut) {
        this.connectionTimeOut = connectionTimeOut;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and show us what you have tried?

Comment: Feroz, how do you expect us to answer to this "question" (there isn't even a question)? What should we say? "Launch activity, show splash until result arrives, and then navigate user"?

Comment: so sorry guys but the code seems to be huge. code is update in question

Comment: We have seen the code you added. But you have to provide a real question

Comment: i have 5 threads parallel  call to happen in background but i need to wait for one specific thread( which is DashBoardCallable)  exectuion so that i can load dashboard data and change the actvity meanwhile in parallel i load some more data related to that user in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the use of your threads I can tell you should be better to use AsyncTask.

Every AsyncTask must have a Callback and the Activity implement them so, after the task was completed, the Activity can keep control of the operations and take decisions.

For the tasks:

```
public class SplashScreenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private Context context;

private SplashScreenTaskCallback listener = null;

public SplashScreenTask (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground (Void... params) {

    // Do your tasks


    return null;
}

@Override
public void onPreExecute () {
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute (Void v) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.OnSplashScreenTaskCompleted ();
    }
}

public void setListener (SplashScreenTaskCallback listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}


public interface SplashScreenTaskCallback {
    void OnSplashScreenTaskCompleted ();
}
}
```

And your activity:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity implements SplashScreenTask.SplashScreenTaskCallback {

protected Runnable postDelayedAction;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    handler.postDelayed(startBackgroundTasks, splashScreenDelay);

}

private Runnable startBackgroundTasks = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run () {

        //  Do initial background tasks like sounds load
        SplashScreenTask task = new SplashScreenTask (SplashScreenActivity.this);
        task.setListener (SplashScreenActivity.this);
        task.execute ();

    }
};

@Override
public void OnSplashScreenTaskCompleted () {
    // Here you take decisions
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir, Async will be better than the thread where should i call my background threads in this case

Comment: its solve my purpose in OnSplashScreenTaskCompleted  i have runned all my background task

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Rx zip operator to determine when all of your backgrounds tasks have completed. Determining the completion of multiple parallel jobs is a huge headache with the Android framework.

There is a best practice for showing a splash screen with no initial delay wherein you set the background drawable using themes. In order to do that and transition into your Activity (not your splash screen) where you can actually fire off all of this logic, simply duplicate the visuals of your splash screen in your Activity, and transition out of showing those visuals once your jobs have completed.